# Get random entry tagged with

Tags: entries, tags

Looking to get a random entry from my database which is tagged with 'featured', is this possible at all? I've seen randomised by just the entry loop but nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try customizing the order parameter. MySQL allows ordering randomly by using `.. ORDER BY rand()`. So you could try the following:

```
craft.entries.section('featured').order('rand()').first()
```